# Hashing an unordered list of lists in python

Tags: python, hash, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, backtracking

I am coding a backtracking depth first search algorithm that has many answers.

I want all of them, but I know I am doing redundant work. (in fact over k! times, where k is the number of sets)

I have a list of lists that their union is the set of numbers 1 through n, without any repeats.

I am looking for a way to see if I have checked a combination before.

For example: A = [ [1,2,4], [ 3 ] ] should be the same as B = [ [3], [1,2,4] ]

The range of numbers will always be less than 3^k where (k+1) is the number of sets.

Meaning for 3 sets, the range of numbers is less than 9.
For 4 sets, the range of numbers is less than 27 (in actually it is 17) and so on.
In fact if A_n represents the smallest number that will need n sets, then A_n <= 3 * A_(n-1) for n > 1. (I havn't proved it, but am pretty certain)

I've come up with some terrible solutions, but thought I'd post them and see if they give anyone an idea.

1: I hash each list for a total of k hashes per list, then do something mathematical, (add, multiply, etc) and then hash. Or just put it in a tuple itself and hash it. Example:

```
A = [ [1,2,4], [3] ]
def hashIt(A):
   x = [hash(tuple(y)) for y in A]
   x.sort()
   return hash(tuple(x))
```

2: If I have less than 3^10 numbers, I guess I can create an integer n numbers long, each place symbolizing which set it is in.

Ex: 
A = [ [1,2,4], [3] ] would be 0010. Because 1 is in the 0th list, 2 in 0th list, 3 in the 1st ...
B = [ [3], [1,2,4] ] would be 1101. Because 1 is in the 1st list, 2 in 1st list, 3 in the 0th ...

I can then change a number into its chronological smallest form, since swapping all the ones with zeros and zeros with ones, will net be a smaller number, so it is chronologically smaller as well. Doing this with 10 sets, would be extremely slow, but still faster than checking every possible set.

If I have three sets, A = [ [1, 2, 4, 8], [3, 5, 6, 10], [7, 9] ] and B = [ [7,9], [1, 2, 4, 8], [3, 5, 6, 10] ]. Then 
change_To_Hashable(A) = 0010112021 
change_To_Hashable(B) = 1121220102

Here we have to swap 2 with 0 and then 1 with 2.

But with C = [ [1, 2, 4, 9], [3, 5, 6], [7, 8, 10] ]
change_To_Hashable(C) = 0010112202

3: Sort each list when you want to check and store, this way searching isn't too painful

4: Start by searching for list with 1 in it, then go through that list

Method one seems to be the fastest, but I'd like to do some serious number crunching once I have a reasonable solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you getting the lists initially?  You may have an easier time if you sort the lists at the time you create them, so you can check if each one exists before you add it to your collection.  Also, do you need them to be lists?  If you use sorted tuples you can just put them in a set.

Comment: I am generating the lists using some math and checking if a number can be placed in a set. In a nutshell, I try and place a number in each set, if it can be placed, great, otherwise, try next set. And backtrack when appropriate.

Comment: The lists are always sorted since I append the number to the appropriate set

Comment: Sorry, I mean the lists of lists.  When you create a list like your A, B, or C, can you sort it (and/or make it a tuple) at the time of creation?

Comment: @BrenBarn I can't make it a tuple since I will be modifying each list in the list of lists as I am backtracking when I can't place a number in the last set. Each list will be sorted automatically since I go from 1 -> n and pop the elements out of the list when I backtrack. I am currently trying to figure out how to have the lists sorted relative to each other now.